# Why is it a syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Simple query like this.

```
MyModel.where('student_id = :id AND from <= :date AND to >= :date', {:id => student.id, :date => day.to_s(:db)})
```

Returns an exception

```
=> ActiveRecord::JDBCError: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from <= '2017-02-28 00:00:00.000' AND to >= '2017-02-28 00:00:00.000')'
```

And I don't get why.

Comment: `FROM` is a reserved keyword of MySQL

Comment: @Raptor shoot. This is what I was thinking of. But my table has a field `from`. What should I do then?

Comment: Simple: Rename it. Avoid using reserved words in column name as well as table name.

Comment: @Forward not recommended, as this will be confusing

Comment: @Raptor sure, but we have 500 000 people in this DB already, so I would like to move the path of least resistance :D

Comment: Oops, then adding backtick is the only solution, or you have to rename the DB column as well as all related codes at your next maintenance window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From is a reserved  word  you should use backtics when you have a column name `from`  (better if you don't use column names based on reserved  words)

```
MyModel.where('student_id = :id 
                  AND `from` <= :date 
                  AND `to` >= :date', {:id => student.id, :date => day.to_s(:db)})
```

Comment: I don't see a point in giving the answer to this question, since *identical* problems were solved here (SO) hundreds of times. Users like you (experienced + you have golded mysql badge) should rather close these questions as duplicates.